# spring boot controllers not getting registered; getting 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am running spring-boot application in intellij and all of my scheduled tasks and everything is working fine but my controller which i have registered with @RestController and @RequestMapping are not getting registered. I am getting 404 when trying to access these while same is working fine when i am using eclipse.
Even my ide console is showing rest controller as registered:

```
RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Mapped "{[/api/{v1}/restaurant/{cloudSiteId}/staff/{staffId}],methods=[GET]}" onto private java.lang.Object com.limetray.inventory.controller.StaffLocationController.getStaffDetail
```

Not able to guess what might go wrong ?

Comment: We need more information than this. What is the path you're going to? How does the method `getStaffDetail()` look like? You can always take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your controller is in a separate package from your Main class you can try adding a component scan to your main class pointing to the package you have your controllers in.  Example:

```
@ComponentScan({ "x.y.z.myPackage1", "x.y.z.myPackage2" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a matter of deployment, and you've to edit the run configuartion for your webapp. Menu `Run` , then `Edit configurations ...`. Or this button in the toolbar:

[image: Toolbar]

This example is for a simple servlet, no Spring, but it gives you hints.
[image]

[image]